# Is it possible to synchronize Javascript between browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs, synchronization

I have a web application that people are often using with multiple open tabs. Each tab also connects to an external server via websockets. I have no control over that server and it frequently broadcasts various messages to all the open tabs. For some of the messages I'd like the tabs to notify my own server via simple ajax.

The problem is that EVERY open tab will want to contact my server and thus create unnecessary load - I only need one notification.

I will filter out duplicate notifications server-side anyway, because the users might have multiple open browsers (rare, but it does happen), however for typical everyday usage (single browser with multiple tabs) I'd like to minimize the redundant requests.

**How can I do this?**

The best way for cross-tab communication seems to be `localStorage`, however there isn't anything there about synchronization. There are no guarantees when my writes to the storage will be visible to other tabs.

Comment: Look up `postMessage`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Good, but I'd need to get the `window` object of the other tabs. How do I do that?

Comment: `window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {});` this simple example seems to sync between tabs https://codepen.io/tevko/pen/GgWYpg

Comment: Ah, you're right, it doesn't look possible without having a reference to the other window

Comment: @NicolòCozzani - The problem is, I don't think it's enough. When I write in tab A, the event in tab B can happen later, much later (in practice it's almost instantaneous, but there are no guarantees anywhere...). Even worse, I don't know _when_ tab B will see the changes that tab A made. If the broadcast event arrives at the same time in both tabs, and both tabs try to write to the same place at the same time, one will win, but how long will it take for the other one to see that it lost? How can either tab know if it won or lost?